# Using Cut and Not in Prolog Programming

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

I am new to Prolog Programming. So I want to know following. I know the use of Cut (!) in Prolog. Can somebody explain me, the use of Not in Prolog ,when and how to use Not & how to rewrite the following with out using Cut and avoiding the backtracking. ( using only predicates)

```
choose (0,_,[]) :- !.
choose (N,[H|T], [H|R]) :- M is N-1, Choose (M,T,R).
choose(N, [_|T],R) :- Choose(N,T,R)
```

And explain me how to rewrite the following (using only predicates)

```
chooseAll(N,L,Res) :-
    chooseAll(N,L,[],Res).

chooseAll(N,L,Seen,Res):-
    choose(N,L,R),
    not(member(R,Seen)),
    !,
    chooseAll(N,L,[R|Seen],Res).
chooseAll(_,_,Res,Res).
```

Comment: Nitpick: you are new to Prolog programming, not "novel" to it. Prolog may be "novel" to you but never the other way around. :)

Comment: `choose (0,_,[]) :- !.` is invalid syntax. there mustn't be a space between a predicate name and the opening parenthesis following it.

Answer (score 3):

[**`not/1`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=not/1) is a predicate with one parameter: the *goal* (in your example `member(R,Seen)`).

It works according to ***negation as finite failure* principle**. It means that `not(P)` succeeds, given Prolog finds *no* way to satisfy `P`. In other words, if you would query Prolog for `P` directly, it would return `false`. If Prolog however gets into a infinite loop with `P`, it will also loop forever in `not(P)`.

If on the other hand `P` succeeds (with unification or not), `not(P)` will fail.

Since it only succeeds if `P` is `false`, no unification will be done in `not`. In case `P` succeeds, `not(P)` fails and any unifications done are thus undone.

So `not(member(R,Seen))` checks whether `R` is *not* a member of `Seen`. In case `Seen` is a variable, `not(member(R,Seen))` will fail. Given `R` is a variable, `not(member(R,Seen))` will succeed given `Seen` is not an empty list.

The cut **`!`** on the other hand has nothing to do with `not/1`. In your example it simply means that if `not(member(R,Seen)` succeds, the cut will be executed, and thus the redo on the last `chooseAll/1` will not be done in that case.

So how does the `chooseAll/4` predicate works? It is called with `Seen` as an empty list. In the first clause, we first call `choose(N,L,R)` which generates a combination of numbers into a list `R`. We want to prevent that the same list is generated again and again, and thus next use a `not(member(R,Seen))` call to check whether `R` is already in `Seen`. For the first result, this is not the case, so we cut `!` to prevent the system from backtracking and selecting the last clause and next we call `chooseAll` recursively but with `R` added to the `Seen` list.

In the recursive call, we ask again `choose/3` to generate a combination `R` and add it to the seen list. But now it will generate the same result as the first time: `choose/3` will for each call create answers in the same order. So that means Prolog will backtrack over `not(member(R,Seen))` and ask `choose/3` to generate the next combination. That combination will not be part of `Seen`, so `not(member(R,Seen))` will succeed and as a result we will again cut and make a recursive call with `R` added to `Seen`.

This will keep going on until `choose/3` is complete exhausted and fails to come up with a combination `R` that is not yet part of `Seen`. In that case, Prolog will backtrack over the `chooseAll/4` predicate and thus execute the last one, which unifies the result `Res` with the `Seen` list.

This is however an inefficient approach: for each answer we generate, we will call the predicate again until it generates a new answer. Therefore an ISO predicate the [**`findall/3`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) predicate. It will put all the results of a predicate in a list (and not in a reverse order). We can use it like:

```
chooseAll(N,L,Res) :-
    findall(R,choose(N,L,R),Res).
```

**Note**: as the [documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=not/1) on `not/1` specifies:

> True if `Goal` cannot be proven. **Retained for compatibility only. New code should use [`\+/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%5C%2B)/1)**.

So you better use `\+ member(R,Seen)` since it is more *mnemonic*.

Comment: I would encourage people to use `\+/1` instead of `not/1`. Also, you mean infinite loop in paragraph 2. Otherwise amazing answer!

Answer (score 2):

Please let us take a brief step back and consider a few issues that are more general than how to use one or two specific predicates such as `!/0` or `not/1`.

First, let us fix a few **syntax issues**, and let your original code read:

```
choose(0,_,[]) :- !.
choose(N,[H|T], [H|R]) :- M is N-1, choose(M,T,R).
choose(N, [_|T],R) :- choose(N,T,R).

chooseAll(N,L,Res) :-
    chooseAll(N,L,[],Res).

chooseAll(N,L,Seen,Res):-
    choose(N,L,R),
    not(member(R,Seen)),
    !,
    chooseAll(N,L,[R|Seen],Res).
chooseAll(_,_,Res,Res).
```

Starting from this, I apply the following two minor changes:

- Instead of `not/1`, I use `(\+)/1`, because `(\+)/1` is ISO but `not/1` is, well, *not*.
- Instead of `(is)/2`, I use the CLP(FD) constraint `(#=)/2` to advertise more recent language constructs and make explicit that we are reasoning *only* over **integers** in this case, not for example floats or other kinds of numbers. Think of this as guaranteeing additional *type safety*.

We these two small changes we obtain:

```
choose(0,_,[]) :- !.
choose(N,[H|T], [H|R]) :- M #= N-1, choose(M,T,R).
choose(N, [_|T],R) :- choose(N,T,R).

chooseAll(N,L,Res) :-
    chooseAll(N,L,[],Res).

chooseAll(N,L,Seen,Res):-
    choose(N,L,R),
    \+ member(R,Seen),
    !,
    chooseAll(N,L,[R|Seen],Res).
chooseAll(_,_,Res,Res).
```

Now **let's start**! I am eager to try out the main predicate by asking: *Which solutions are there at all?*

To find out, I post the so-called **most general** query, where all arguments are fresh variables:

```
?- chooseAll(X, Y, Z).
X = 0,
Z = [[]].
```

*What?* There is only a single solution of this predicate, right? *Right?*

## Probably not.

So, I would like to get more answers for such basic questions. To get them, I make the following additional changes:

- I **remove the `!/0`**.
- I use **`dif/2`** to state that two terms are *different*.
- I slightly reorder the clauses.
- I add the constraints `N #> 0` for those clauses that only apply if `N` is greater than 0.

So, we have:

```
choose(0,_,[]).
choose(N,[H|T], [H|R]) :- N #> 0, M #= N-1, choose(M,T,R).
choose(N, [_|T],R) :- N #> 0, choose(N,T,R).

chooseAll(N,L,Res) :-
    chooseAll(N,L,[],Res).

chooseAll(_,_,Res,Res).
chooseAll(N,L,Seen,Res):-
    choose(N,L,R),
    maplist(dif(R), Seen),
    chooseAll(N,L,[R|Seen],Res).
```

And now we have for example:

```
?- chooseAll(X, Y, Z).
Z = [] ;
X = 0,
Z = [[]] ;
X = 1,
Y = [_1966|_1968],
Z = [[_1966]] ;
X = 1,
Y = [_3214, _3220|_3222],
Z = [[_3220], [_3214]],
dif(_3220, _3214) ;
X = 1,
Y = [_3560, _3566, _3572|_3574],
Z = [[_3572], [_3566], [_3560]],
dif(_3572, _3560),
dif(_3572, _3566),
dif(_3566, _3560) .
X = 0,
Z = [[]].
```

I leave it as an exercise to figure out if this program is now too general, too specific or both, and to either add or remove the necessary *constraints* to obtain *only* the desired answers.

The main point I wanted to show is that sticking to pure predicates helps you to obtain much more general programs. Using `!/0` and `(\+)/1` doesn't help with that. To avoid backtracking in specific cases while retaining the predicate's generality, use for example the new predicate `if_/3`.